# There's a left and top gap on the page and backgrounds don't change on wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am working on a theme on wordpress and created a page template called newpage-template.php and the code is like this:

```
<div class="akmos">

   <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/imagens/banner-akmos.png">

</div>
```

but there's a gap on the left and top (but not on the right), just like you can see here:

[image]

My CSS for this page is:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Stuff */ ?>
.akmos {
   height: 500px;
 }

.akmos img {
   width:100%
}
```

I already set up the margin:0, but it doesn't work.

```
body {
margin:0 !important;
}
```

The weirdest thing is that I can't change the size of the image via css, it doesn't work. If I try to put it width to 400px, for example, it won't change. It makes me believe that the problem is with php, but I'm not sure. How to resolve it?

Comment: For Image use padding 0px. like .akmos img { padding:0px,
   width:100%
}

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle for your case. There must be other CSS properties / classes affecting the layout.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the `width:100%` of your `.akmos img` doesn't 'work' is because you did not declare a width in the parent div, i.e. `.akmos`. I suggest setting up the dimensions in `.akmos` and telling `.akmos img` to follow the parent's attributes:

```
.akmos {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;margin-top:0px;
  left:0;margin-left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
}

.akmos img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

See if this works :)

Comment: Wrong. Multiple CSS problems here: 1. if the value is `0`, no unit is needed; 2. adding `height: 100%` to the image might distort the image (use `height: auto` instead); 3. displaying the `.akmos` as `fixed` might lead to other issues (OP might not want to "stick" the element at a fixed position)